# Error inflating EditText but weirdly after commenting it in my layout the app starts and works fine

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is my layout for launcher activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:shadowColor="@color/iron"
            android:text="Login"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and LoginActivity

```
    package com.android.symptoma;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

When i launch the app on my emulator i get

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.symptoma/com.android.symptoma.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class EditText**

However, when i comment out both EditText everything works fine. Any ideas why i have such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following dependencies in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

and try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/testingInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/testingEditText"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/testText"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `TextInputEditText`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```